# Reindex documents, text and integer fields in elasticsearch 7

Tags: elasticsearch, text, integer, mapping, schema

```
GET paganotti_civile_nuovo/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "numerosentenza": 1105
    }
  }
}
```

Run this query in elasticsearch 7 it return these fields:

```
"codicesezione" : "S1",
"senderid" : "DVSDRD44E18E438B",
"numerosentenza" : "1105",
"_version_" : "1607812642583347200",
```

numerosentenza is text because "1105", but I set mapping paganotti_civile_nuovo numerosentenza as integer.
You can see here:

```
GET paganotti_civile_nuovo/_mapping/field/numerosentenza
{
  "paganotti_civile_nuovo" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "numerosentenza" : {
        "full_name" : "numerosentenza",
        "mapping" : {
          "numerosentenza" : {
            "type" : "integer"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I done reindex in this way:

```
POST _reindex?wait_for_completion=false
{
  "source": {
    "index": "paganotti_civile"
  },
  "dest": {
    "index": "paganotti_civile_nuovo"
  },
  "script": {
    "lang": "painless",
    "source": "ctx._id = ctx._source._id"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works by design. If the field mapping is set to `integer` but you sent a stringified integer `"1105"` instead of an integer value `1105`, it's ok as ES will automatically try to [coerce the string value into the integer value](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/coerce.html).

However, ES will NOT modify your source document, so if you send `"1105"`, you'll retrieve `"1105"` from your _source document even though `1105` is actually indexed.